# chipmunk sprite area by vertex

Tags: iphone, xcode, sprite, chipmunk

Is there any application which will give the vertex point form my sprite.
I want to define my each sprite area.
almost like spritehelper, you know that to use spritehelper you need to buy it. actually i don't have enough money to buy it.
I dont like to buy it. I am searching similar software.

I want to find out the vertex point value to define the area of a sprite.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the trial version of [PhysicsEditor](http://www.physicseditor.de/) and [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com/).

PhysicsEditor can provide you vertexes points of the shape. If you wish to use multiple images then you can take help from TexturePacker.

Hope it helps.